# Object changes its properties during manipulation

Tags: transparency, .fbx

I have a problem with a object block given by the manufacturer. It was an STP file and I converted in in FBX. When I import the file, it somehow behaves strange because everytime I turn the object, it makes cuts in object so I can see through it (see pics). I can see bolts and connections inside it but that is not what I want. All I want is to have a whole object which I can manipulate with and whcih makes no changes, no cuts etc. Also the mesh in Blender gets narrower every time I move the object. I don't where the problem is but it might be a different focus?

Can someone help me?
Thank you!

Here is the fbx file I import: https://gofile.io/d/Bj965A

[image: Picture 1]
[image: Picture 2]
[image: Picture 3]

Comment: your fbx file cannot be accessed, something wrong with the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the *N* panel, under *View > View*, tweak the *Clip Start* and *End* values:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, it was very helpful. I set a different view and it works just how I wanted :).